# Area of a quadrilateral

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have *n* points in a plane and a target area *P*. I am trying to find four points which have an area which are the corners of a quadrilateral with area closest value to *P*. Here is an example with *n*=5 and *P*=30:

- 0, 0
- 10, 0
- 0, 10
- 10, 10
- 7, 3

The answer should be 30.0 (the closest one to *P*, in this case it's equal).

Do you have any ideas how I could do this? I know I can calculate the area  of each quadrilateral using Heron's formula, but do I have to try every combination or is there some shorter way?

Comment: Heron's formula works on triangles, and its natural extension to quadrilaterals, called Brahmagupta's formula, applies only to cyclic quadrilaterals, not to general quadrilaterals.

Comment: You can use Bretschneider's formula though. You'll need to use some trig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I can't think of an algorithm that improves on the worst-case iterating over all possible quadrilaterals. If the area is small compared to the the area over which the points are spread you could use a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) arrangement to weed out points which are too far away to make a reasonable quadrilateral. But even there you have to be careful, since it's possible that a very thin quadrilateral with distant points will have just the right area, so you might have to resign yourself to the quartic algorithm.

But you can use a speedup: when you have three points, find the area of the associated triangle, and if it's larger than abs(target area - best area so far) then you don't need to try any values for the fourth point.

As I mentioned in the comments you need [Bretschneider's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula) for the quadrilateral areas, Heron's is for triangles.

Comment: Well, I know Heron's is for triangle xd I thought to actually calculate its area as 2 triangles. But anyway, I did the bruteforce, with 4 for loops. It worked fine with testcases I tried, so I hope it'll pass theirs too. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3751721 Yes, you can do that. Is it obvious that they won't cross?

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. take a unit/template polygon with the desired number of vertices and shape .
2. add a multiplicative scale factor `t` to it, so that its coordinates look like

   ```
   0, 0
   10t, 0
   0, 10t
   10t, 10t
   7t, 3t
   ```
3. Use the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) to figure out the area, say `f(t)`.
4. Solve the polynomial equation `f(t) = 30.0` for the scaling factor `t` and the associated coordinates of your polygon.

This should give you a polygon of the area you wanted (`30.0`).

By the way, I assume you know the shape of the polygon, for otherwise, there are (infinitely) many solutions that can fit your target area.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Green's theorem](https://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_find_area) and perform a contour integration around the perimeter segments using Gaussian quadrature. No quadrilaterals needed that way.

This approach will work even with areas with cutouts inside.  You would integrate along internal segments connecting each one.